# Read XML from URL with C not C++ in Win32 application

Tags: c, xml, url, winapi, visual-studio-2012

I code in C and I am little weak in C++, in my research I came across many methods to read XML from URL for my win32 application. 
I found cURL and `XmlTextReader` but it's in C++.
Is there any function or other ways, where I can download XML from the URL and parse that XML using only C language and not C++?

I can work with C++ as well, but I want to avoid it as it's not I am comfortable with.

Comment: Use websearch to answer this, here it is off topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) has pure C API. [Expat](http://www.jclark.com/xml/expat.html) and [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) are written in pure C too.

Comment: Microsoft also has its own WinInet/WinHTTP APIs for downloading data from a URL, and its own MSXML library for parsing XML. Both are usable in C, if you are not worried about supporting non-Windows platforms. The libcurl and libxml libraries are cross-platform.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Windows Internet (WinINet)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385331.aspx) or [Windows HTTP Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384273.aspx) for download. [WinHTTP vs. WinINet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh227297.aspx) offers an overview to help you decide, which API to use.

To parse XML content, you can use [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742.aspx). It is Microsoft's XML parser (both DOM and SAX), that is exposed as a COM interface. Using COM from C is somewhat verbose, but fairly straight forward.

When using either of the above, you do not need to ship any additional libraries with your application.